# Does a distribution with the moments $E[X^k]=1_{k=2l} l!$ exists?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, distribution-theory

Does a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ exists such that for a random variable $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with said distribution we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^{2l}] = l! \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \mathbb{E}[X^{2l+1}] = 0
$$
for all $l \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

The equality $\mathbb{E}[X^{2l+1}] = 0$ clearly holds for every symmetric distribution (where the moments exist) but I don't know of a distribution with such even moments.

Any help is much apprechiated.

Comment: Search Wikipedia for 'The Moment Problem'. There is a graduate text by Springer with this title.

Comment: You could look for a $Y$ with $\mathbb E\left[Y^l\right]=l!$ and then let $X=\pm\sqrt{Y}$ with equal probability.  A little bit of extra work would let you specify the distribution more simply

Comment: Thanks! With these two comments the question now becomes whether the matrices $H_n$ for $(H_n)_{i,j} = (i+j)!$ are positive semidefinite.

Comment: I just managed to show that these matrices are positive definite with Laplace expansion, meaning such a distribution must exist. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a much simpler way if you follow @Henry's comment: Let $Y$ have the standard exponential distribution. Then for every integer $k\ge0$,
$$\mathbb E[Y^k]=\int_0^\infty y^k\mathrm e^{-y}\,\mathrm dy=\Gamma(k+1)=k!.$$
So consider $X=\varepsilon\sqrt Y$ where $\varepsilon$ is an independent Rademacher variable.

Comment: the density for $X$ is $f(x)=|x|\, e^{-x^2}$ over the reals

Comment: haha, yeah that's a lot simpler. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*From comments:*

You could look for a $Y$ with $\mathbb E\left[Y^n\right]=n!$ and then let $X=\pm\sqrt{Y}$ with equal probability. A little bit of extra work would let you specify the distribution more simply.

Such a $Y$ is well known: it is the exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

This leads to $X$ having density $$f(x)=|x|\, e^{-x^2}$$ over the reals, as illustrated below.  This is clearly symmetric about $0$, so the odd moments are $0$. A relatively simple integration shows the even moments are the desired factorials.

[image]

Comment: [+1] One could probably call it the symmetric [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution)$(\frac1{\sqrt2})$ distribution but this does not seem very common.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution relying of generating functions and some simple guesswork.

We are looking for a function $f(x)$ obeying the equation

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x) x^{2 k} \, dx=k!\tag{1}$$

Multiplying by $(-z)^k$ and trying to sum over $k$ needs a convergence forcing factor. The most natural choice is $\frac{1}{k!}$.

Since on the l.h.s. under the integral we have

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(x^2 (-z)\right)^k}{k!}=e^{-x^2 z}\tag{2}$$

and on the r.h.s.

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }(-z)^k=\frac{1}{1+z}$$

We find for $f(x)$ in place of $(1)$

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(x)e^{-x^2 z} \, dx=\frac{1}{1+z}\tag{3}$$

In order to generate somehow $1+z$ in the denominator we let

$$f(x) = e^{-x^2} g(x)$$

with $g(x) = g(-x)$ so that

$$2 \int_{0 }^{\infty } g(x)e^{-x^2 (1+z)} \, dx=\frac{1}{1+z}$$

Now since $d(x^2) = 2 x dx$ we find that $g(x) = x$ gives the desired solution for $x\gt 0$. Extending this to negative $x$ gives $g(x) = |x|$, and the final result becomes

$$f(x) = |x|e^{-x^2}\tag{4}$$

This coincides with the result derived in a different manner by other users.